# How to create an azure image from a snapshot?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, iaas

I have taken a snapshot of a VM running as a managed disk.  Now i want to create multiple vm's using that snapshot.

Can someone tell me how to create an image from that snapshot ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/snapshot-copy-managed-disk ?

Answer (score 5):

You can create the image from a snapshot using Powershell.

1. Create the variables

```
    $rgName = "myResourceGroup"`
    $location = "EastUS"
    $snapshotName = "mySnapshot"
    $imageName = "myImage"
```

2. Get the snapshot

```
    $snapshot = Get-AzureRmSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $rgName -SnapshotName $snapshotName
```

3. Create the image configuration

```
    $imageConfig = New-AzureRmImageConfig -Location $location
    $imageConfig = Set-AzureRmImageOsDisk -Image $imageConfig -OsState Generalized -OsType Windows -SnapshotId $snapshot.Id
```

4. Create the Image

```
    New-AzureRmImage -ImageName $imageName -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Image $imageConfig
```

The link for the same can be found here: [Capture Image Resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource)

Answer (score 1):

We can use **PowerShell** to create Image from managed disk.
 More information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource#create-a-managed-image-from-a-snapshot-using-powershell).

By the way, if you want to create image from this snapshot, we should **generalize** it first.